# inserting multiple images into a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am creating a form to insert images into a slider, with a maximum of 10 slides. When inserting the images i need the option of being able to choose maybe just 2,3 or 4 slides for example. But when i try to inset less than the 10 image, it does not insert into the database.

Here is what i have thus far;

```
try {

    //$max_size = 2097152;  This is to do, not part of question
    $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');

    $img_1 = $_FILES['slider_1']['name'];

    $extn   =   strtolower(end(explode('.', $img_1)));
    $temp   =   $_FILES['slider_1']['tmp_name'];

    if(in_array($extn, $allowed) === true) {
        $slider_1 = 'data/' . md5(time().uniqid()) . '.' . $extn;
        move_uploaded_file($temp, $slider_1);
    }

//This works upto this point

$insert = DB::getInstance()->insert('slider', array(
    'main'      =>  $main,
    'slider_1'  =>  $slider_1,
    'slider_2'  =>  $slider_2,
    'slider_3'  =>  $slider_3,
    'slider_4'  =>  $slider_4,
    'slider_5'  =>  $slider_5,
    'slider_6'  =>  $slider_6,
    'slider_7'  =>  $slider_7,
    'slider_8'  =>  $slider_8,
    'slider_9'  =>  $slider_9,
    'slider_10' =>  $slider_10
));

    Session::flash('success', '<p class="success">Inserted successfully</p>');
    Redirect::to('test.php');

} catch(Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

Here is my insert function

```
public function insert($table, $fields = array()) {
    $keys   = array_keys($fields);
    $values = null;
    $x      = 1;

    foreach($fields as $value) {
        $values .= "?";
        if($x < count($fields)) {
            $values .= ', ';
        }
        $x++;
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO {$table} (`" . implode('`, `', $keys) . "`) VALUES ({$values})";

    if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

And here is my form

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">

    <label for="main"><span class="required">*</span> Main Image:</label>
    <input type="file" name="main">
    <label for="img_set_1"><span class="required">*</span> Image Set 1:</label>
    <input type="file" name="slider_1">
    <label for="img_set_2"><span class="required">*</span> Image Set 2:</label>
    <input type="file" name="slider_2">
    <label for="img_set_3"><span class="required">*</span> Image Set 3:</label>
    <input type="file" name="slider_3">
    <label for="img_set_4"><span class="required">*</span> Image Set 4:</label>
    <input type="file" name="slider_4">
    <label for="img_set_5"><span class="required">*</span> Image Set 5:</label>
    <input type="file" name="slider_5">
    <label for="img_set_6"><span class="required">*</span> Image Set 6:</label>
    <input type="file" name="slider_6">
    <label for="img_set_7"><span class="required">*</span> Image Set 7:</label>
    <input type="file" name="slider_7">
    <label for="img_set_8"><span class="required">*</span> Image Set 8:</label>
    <input type="file" name="slider_8">
    <label for="img_set_9"><span class="required">*</span> Image Set 9:</label>
    <input type="file" name="slider_9">
    <label for="img_set_10"><span class="required">*</span> Image Set 10:</label>
    <input type="file" name="slider_10">
    <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">

</form>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: no error, just not inserting into the Database. If i comment out all the insert array, except 'slider_1' => $slider_1, and all the form inputs except name="slider_1" then it works perfectly. But i need to be able to just choose as many as i want with a max of 10 without commenting out the array

Comment: what do you get when you echo $sql

Comment: It appears you only process '$_FILES['slider_1']', what about the others, '$_FILES['slider_2']' etc.? If you var_dump($_FILES]) you will see what data is in it. It may be useful to use an array name in the 'file' widget of the  html  form of ' name="slider[]". In your code the '$slider_2' .. variables will be undefined.

Comment: This is the query from echo of $sql ----  INSERT INTO slider (`main`, `slider_1`, `slider_2`, `slider_3`, `slider_4`, `slider_5`, `slider_6`, `slider_7`, `slider_8`, `slider_9`, `slider_10`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Comment: Ryan: I have tried to do that but it then inserts the same image in all slides